# Test suite, Test plan, Test cases for Android application

Tags: manual-testing, android, testcase, test-planning, excel

I have been asked to learn about Test Plan, Test Suite, Black Box Testing, Test Cases. Can anyone guide me in which order should I start learning?

And also what are the necessary test cases for Android application testing and how to write test cases in excel?

Answer (score 2):

1. Test Plan
2. Test Suite
3. Black-box Testing
4. Test Cases

**Test Plan**: In Test plan you can understand whole application, Flow on your android application and after create test plan & test cases.

**Black-box testing:** Testing without having any knowledge of the interior workings of the application is called black-box testing.Black box testing includes only input and output process

**Test Suite:** Test suite means validation. check all validation for mandatory fields

**Test Case:** Create test case for your mobile application continue to testing period.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when it comes to implementation , correct order is :

1 - Create Test Plan

2 - Create Test Cases

3 - Execute Test Cases [It includes all testing. i.e Blackbox]

> what are the necessary test cases for application testing?

Mostly it is depends on what flow and functionality application includes. You can check common mobile application check list : [Mobile App. Testing Checklist](http://www.tmap.net/sites/.../Checklist_Mobile_App_Testing_0.docx)

> how to write test cases in excel?

Please download best test case sample from here : [Login Test case Sample](http://thesoftwaretesting.com/test-cases/)

I hope these all help you better.

Comment: "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /sites/.../Checklist_Mobile_App_Testing_0.docx on this server" the error message i got, when i clicked "Mobile App. Testing Checklist". do you have the file?

Comment: Yes I have.......

Comment: can u upload it in google drive or Dropbox? and post the link.

Comment: Sorry , I can not do that. you can search in google by query `mobile testing checklist :pdf` , you will get lot of documents.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been asked to learn about Test Plan, Test Suite, Black Box Testing, Test Cases

I would like you to summon our search god, known to us as Google. One query and there is a bucket full of results returned, which have all the information that you need. I expect, most likely your prayer would be answered.

Go by this order :

- **Black Box Testing** :  A software testing technique whereby the internal workings of the item being tested are not known by the tester.

Read more at [Black Box Testing](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/Black_Box_Testing.html)

- **Test Cases** : A test case is a set of conditions or a set of variables according to which a tester would test or determine if the system is working as per requirements.

Read more at [Test Cases](https://qatechnicals.wordpress.com/fundamentals/test-cases/)

- **Test Plan** : A test plan is the official documentation that lists scope and activities. It gives you a baseline while formally testing a software product or a module.

Read more at [Test Plan](https://qatechnicals.wordpress.com/fundamentals/test-plan/)

- **Test Suite** : Test suite is a container that has a set of tests which helps testers in executing and reporting the test execution status.

Read more at [Test Suite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/test_suite.htm)

Now, more often than not, starters seem to have a confusion in getting difference between Test Plan and Test Suite. Here is a good [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9119/test-suite-vs-test-plan) to understand the difference.

Now, coming to part 2 of your question-

> And also what are the necessary test cases for Android application testing

This is a very broad question. And it depends solely, how your application is designed and how it works.

You can create test cases based on exploring your application and refer to this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/how-to-write-proper-test-case-steps) on how to write good test cases. If your application is based on a requirement, you can design test cases, which cover the requirements. Otherwise, explore the app and try to think about the cases/scenarios that user may face.

For example, if your application needs an email login- then you can create scenarios when a user tries to log in using

- *valid id and valid password*
- *invalid id and invalid password*
- *no id and password*
- *invalid id (or password) and valid id(password) and vice-versa*.

Now to next part of your question

> how to write test cases in excel

There are a lot of templates available on web. Summon the search god and it shall reply. You can copy one of those and use that, in your test plan. Above template provided (by Helping Hands), should be a good start.

Update : I found a very good example of a basic test case template here :[Test Case Template](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5383/looking-for-an-excellent-example-of-using-a-spreadsheet-for-test-case-management)
And, also [here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-case-template-examples/).

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, i searched google before asking this, but was confused since i am new to testing. And also, there is lot of templates, that's why i dint knew which one to follow. however, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can have the most basic template and start with it.  I will edit my answer with a sample test case template

Comment: I have edited the answer with links to some basic test case templates.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, today I believe that most businesses don't care for many papers, delivered value, go for it. Forget test cases, test plans. *A mind map can help you much more*.

Today most environments are agile, no one has time to look at thousands of papers with a lot of text. Using a *mindmap* you can "draw" your ideas and be faster and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Please do visit the site: http://www.softwaretestingclass.com. Very practical details about types of testing and how to write test cases, test plan. Even there is particular section for Mobile Testing.

Comment: thank you, but i have gone through that website earlier. i need particularly for android app testing and/or ios app testing, like how to test manually the apps,

Answer (score 0):

@Ripal Patel had provided best solution in addition to that you should be good at concept of "Test Plan, Test Suite, Black Box Testing, Test Cases" all these things, refer this [link](http://www.ministryoftesting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/SmartBear-Mobile-Testing-Checklist-V2.pdf) it will help you to create Test Scenarion and Test cases for Mobile App